husky pre-commit fail for lint staged. yarn format:fix failed without output (FAILED). husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
While using commit, I am getting pre-commit error from husky. If I run yarn lint, yarn lint:fix manually it don't give any error. But when I try to commit it give me error. 
While using commit, I am getting pre-commit error from husky. If I run yarn lint, yarn lint:fix manually it don't give any error. But when I try to commit it gives me error:
"lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
        "yarn format:fix",
        "yarn lint:fix"
    ]
},


when I tried to push it give me yarn format:fix error.
but I t is all ok when I run it manually
